# Prove that semiconvex function can be approximated by smooth functions with same semiconvexity constant

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, viscosity-solutions

On page 60 of [the user's guide to viscosity solutions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9207212.pdf), proof of Lemma A.3, it is stated that given $\varphi$,  a semiconvex function, we can find a smooth approximation $\varphi_\epsilon$ with the same semiconvexity constant as $\varphi$. Is there a reference to this fact? I tried proving it by taking $\varphi_\epsilon$ to be the convolution of $\varphi$ with an approximation to the identity, but it does not seem straightforward to prove that this satisfies the same semiconvexity constant as $\varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of semi-convexity being used here is $\varphi$ is semi-convex with constant $\Lambda > 0$ if $\varphi = \psi + \eta$, where $\psi$ is a convex function and $\eta$ a smooth function with $D^{2} \eta \geq - \Lambda \text{Id}$ (pointwise).  This is equivalent to the inequality $D^{2}\varphi \geq -\Lambda \text{Id}$ in the sense of distributions.  (One direction comes from the fact that $D^{2} (\varphi + \frac{\Lambda}{2} \|\cdot\|^{2}) \geq 0$ in the sense of distributions, making $\varphi + \frac{\Lambda}{2} \|\cdot\|^{2}$ convex and $-\frac{\Lambda}{2} \|\cdot\|^{2}$ is certainly smooth with second derivative actually equal to $-\Lambda \text{Id}$.  The other direction comes a direct computation and properties of convex functions.)

Either definition shows that if $\varphi$ is semi-convex, then the mollified family $\{\varphi^{\epsilon}\}_{\epsilon > 0}$ is also semi-convex.  In either case, we get the same "semi-convexity constant" $\Lambda$.

(Throughout $\varphi^{\epsilon}$ is given by $\varphi^{\epsilon}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \varphi(y) \eta^{\epsilon}(x - y) \, dy$ and $\eta^{\epsilon} \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ satisfies $\eta \geq 0$, $\eta(x) = \eta(-x)$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \eta(x) \, dx = 1$.  We set $\eta^{\epsilon}(\xi) = \epsilon^{-d} \eta(\epsilon^{-1} \xi)$.  Most likely, I will not use the symmetry.  I will assume, though, that $\eta(x) = 0$ if $\|x\| \geq 1$.)

**Approach Using Definition 1:**  Here we have $\varphi = \psi + \eta$ so $\varphi^{\epsilon} = \psi^{\epsilon} + \eta^{\epsilon}$.  Recall that $\psi$ is convex and $\eta$ is smooth.  Hence $\eta^{\epsilon}$ is smooth and we see that all we have to prove is that $\psi$ convex implies $\psi^{\epsilon}$ convex.  (Hence we only really needed to know that $\varphi$ *convex* implies $\varphi^{\epsilon}$ *convex*.)

In the next part of the answer, I will show mollification preserves convexity using the "distributional" approach.  Hence in this part I'll prove it "by hand."

$\psi$ is convex so, for each $x, x' \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we have
\begin{align*}
\psi^{\epsilon}((1 - \lambda)x + \lambda x') &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \psi((1 - \lambda)x + \lambda x' - y) \eta^{\epsilon}(y) \, dy \\ &\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} [(1 - \lambda) \psi(x) + \lambda \psi(x')] \eta^{\epsilon}(y) \, dy \\
&= (1 - \lambda) \psi^{\epsilon}(x) + \lambda \psi^{\epsilon}(x').
\end{align*}
This proves $\psi^{\epsilon}$ is convex.

Similarly, it is not hard to show that $D^{2}\eta^{\epsilon} \geq -\Lambda \text{Id}$ holds.

**Approach Using Definition 2:** We want to show that if $f \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and $f \geq 0$, then
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \varphi^{\epsilon}(x) D^{2}f(x) \, dx \geq -\Lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x) \, dx \cdot \text{Id}.
\end{equation*}

Notice that if $f \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and $f \geq 0$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \varphi^{\epsilon}(x) D^{2}f(x) \, dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \varphi(x - y) D^{2} f(x) \, dx \, \eta^{\epsilon}(y) \, dy \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \varphi(\xi) D^{2} f(\xi + y) \, d\xi \, \eta^{\epsilon}(y) \, dy.
\end{align*}
Since $f(\cdot + y) \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ for each $y \in \{\eta^{\epsilon} > 0\}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \varphi(\xi) D^{2} f(\xi + y) \, d\xi \eta^{\epsilon}(y) \geq - \Lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(\xi + y) \, d \xi \, \eta^{\epsilon}(y) \cdot \text{Id}.
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \varphi^{\epsilon}(x) D^{2}f(x) \, dx \geq -\Lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(\xi + y) \, d \xi \, \eta^{\epsilon}(y) \, dy \cdot \text{Id} = -\Lambda \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x) \, dx \cdot \text{Id}.
\end{equation*}